# In google sheets, can you split string into substrings, perform calculations on substrings and concatenate results in different cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a cell in google sheets with the entry 20/40/40. I would like to create a formula that will split the string into the substrings 20, 40, 40  e.g. s1, s2, s3 = 20, 40, 40. I would then like to perform a different numerical calculation on each of the substrings to get 3 variables e.g. v1, v2, v3 = cell_number*(s1/(100*4)), cell_number*(s2/(100*4)), cell_number*(s3/(100*9)), whereby cell_number refers to the cell reference of a cell containing a numerical value.

I would then like to concatenate these values into a new cell in the same format as the original cell e.g. cell A5 would look like v1/v2/v3.

I would like to do this because the values of s1, s2, s3 will be changing and I must perform this calculation multiple times. If I extend my table it will be unreadable and the only other solution is to make another table with the variations of s1, s2 and s3 I need use and some way concatenate results of the formulas used on these substring variables to give me v1/v2/v3.

I am completely new to google sheets and javascript and at a complete loss at to how to go about it. I did begin to try to create my own function but I am not sure how to approach it in javascript.

Comment: Welcome. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: Currently Apps Script is more or less based upon [Javascript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6).  Read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1:

```
20/40/40
```

B1:(cell_number)

```
5
```

C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("/",B1*(SPLIT(A1,"/")/{100*4,100*4,100*9})))
```

- `SPLIT` A1 by `/` to get numbers. `20|40|40`
- `/` Divide it by a [array](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) of 100. `20/400|40/400|40/900`
- `*` Multiply `cell_number` B1. `5*20/400|5*40/400|5*40/900`
- `JOIN` the result back with `/`